# Vertical Divs swapping well but the content of the corresponding divs overlaps or leave white space

Tags: jquery

Swapping among vertically aligned divs within a parent container div are working fine; but after swapping the moving div accommodate at the new position only when the div already present here earlier has sufficient space; otherwise it overlaps the immediate next div. Similarly if the newly swapped div acquires a new position where the space occupied by the earlier div at this position is more, there is a white space left.

How can the overlapping and white spacings be avoided after swapping?

Comment: Your description is a bit difficult to follow - could you provide an example? Maybe jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using absolute positioning for divs. Is that the case? If yes, change to relative positioning and it should work